# Sorting SQL query from timestamp, id and Unit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

(SQL Server 14.0.3421.10 using Microsoft SQL Server )
I know you guys are always helpful, in this case I don't even know how to google because SQL is not my cup of tea. Code as below

```
declare @refdt  as datetime
declare @loaddt  as datetime
set @refdt='2022-04-01 01:00:00:000'
set @loaddt='2022-04-01 02:00:00:000'

select dt, id, Unit, MIN(pmVoltage) as[test]
from energymeter15min

where (id LIKE '3_4237') and (dt BETWEEN @refdt and @loaddt)

group by dt, Unit, pmVoltage, id
order by Unit, dt
```

Result of this query looks like this

[image]

But I simply want to display the MIN value of pmVoltage in the timespan between @refdt and @loaddt
like this

[image]

Comment: Tip: SQL syntax and functionality can vary a lot by vendor and version. To save time and avoid receiving suggestions that aren't applicable to your DBMS, please [edit] the question to include your database and version in the question tags.

Comment: *where (id LIKE '3_4237')* No need for LIKE unless you're searching for a substring. Since you're matching the whole value, just use equals, i.e. `WHERE id = '3_4237'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try and let me know if it works. It should only display one record for each Unit/id combination which has the lowest pmVoltage value.

```
declare @refdt  as datetime;
declare @loaddt  as datetime;
set @refdt='2022-04-01 01:00:00:000';
set @loaddt='2022-04-01 02:00:00:000';     

With data AS(
  select dt, id, Unit, pmVoltage test
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY Unit, id ORDER BY pmVoltage) rowNum
  from energymeter15min
  where id LIKE '3_4237' 
  and   dt BETWEEN @refdt and @loaddt
)
select dt, id, Unit, test 
from  data
where rowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Austin it look promising but I get this error "Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon."

Comment: @Erik - It's like the error message says, when using a CTE the previous line must terminated with a semicolon, ie. `set @loaddt='2022-04-01 02:00:00:000'; `

Comment: Thank you very much Austin! made my day!
I'm facing a new problem now, I want to import another column "pmMinPowerConsumption" which has the same dt, Unit, id. As I understand in you're example I take in pmVoltage and just sort it, present the lowest value, this wont work when I order 2 columns?

Comment: Glad to help! Can you clarify what end result you are looking for with the additional column? Are you wanting a record for the lowest pmVoltage and a record for the lowest pmMinPowerConsumption for each Unit/id combination?

Answer (score 0):

Try taking pmVoltage out of your GROUP BY - the minimum is determined by the group by, it should not be in it.

```
group by dt, Unit, id
order by Unit, dt
```

Comment: Thank you but I still end up with same results

Answer (score 0):

I Went for a completely different setup

```
declare @refdt as datetime ='2022-04-06 01:00:00:000'
declare @loaddt as datetime ='2022-04-06 04:00:00:000'
declare @id as int =330647 

select min(dt) as startdt, max(dt) as stopdt, 
energymeter15min.id,
Unit,
min(pmVoltage) as minVoltage,
max(pmVoltage) as maxVoltage,
min(pmMinPowerConsumption)as minPowerConsumption,
max(pmMaxPowerConsumption) as maxPowerConsumption
from energymeter15min
join fruname on energymeter15min.frunameid = fruname.id
where (dt between  @refdt and @loaddt ) 
and right(energymeter15min.id,4) in ( right(@id,4) )
and Unit <>'BB-1'
group by energymeter15min.id,Unit
order by Unit asc
```

Were the results are presented like
[image]